# Recovering wifi passwords from keychain

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords

I did a network reset on my iPhone without turning off Keychain it effectively wiped out my wifi passwords on iPhone as well as on my iPad - the passwords are still on laptop in keychain but I can't find away to get them back to my devices,

Is there a way I can recover them from the keychain to my devices

Answer (score 0):

If the operating system is Mac , check the wifi password that is connected.

1. Find "keychain access" in launchpad and open
2. Search for the currently connected Wi-Fi in Keychain Access
3. Right click on the second item of the search results and select "Show Info"
4. Check “Show Password” and enter the password of the computer in the pop-up window.
5. Then you can see the password.

If the operating system is windows, check the wifi password that is connected.

1. Open the Network and Sharing Center and click on the currently connected wifi network icon.
2. In the wlan status interface, we select the wireless property button here and open it.
3. Inside the security of the wireless network properties, we click on the display characters.
4. The password is displayed and you can now see the wireless network wifi password you are connected to.
5. If you have a router, we can enter the router interface to view your wireless router wifi password. The router wireless settings, wireless security settings can view the WiFi password.